# giving the same value to a variable for the same group in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
id    diagnosis
1        a
1        b
1        c
2        d
...
```

I'm trying to create a new variable called `binary` which will be assigned the value of `1` for every group of `id` for which one of entries for `diagnosis` is `a`. Right now my code looks somewhat like this:

```
data temp;
set a.dataset;
if diagnosis = a then binary = 1;
else binary = 0;
run;
```

The output for this looks like:

```
id    diagnosis   binary
1        a          1
1        b          0
1        c          0
2        d          0
...
```

In other words, I want the output to look like this instead:

```
id    diagnosis   binary
1        a          1
1        b          1
1        c          1
2        d          0
...
```

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed the initial data is sorted by id and I have set up some extra input records:

```
data have;
  input id $ diagnosis $;
  datalines;
1        a
1        b
1        c
2        d
2        e
3        f
3        a
;
```

A data step solution could use a merge, e.g.:

```
data want;
  merge have(in=in_h)
        have(in=in_h2 where=(diagnosis='a'));
  by id;

  binary=(in_h=in_h2);
run;
```

If the data is sorted by id *and* diagnosis then you could try:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;

  retain binary;

  if first.id then
    binary=(diagnosis='a');
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Result 1:

```
SELECT id, diagnosis,
       CASE diagnosis WHEN 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS binary
FROM Your_Table
```

Result 2:

```
SELECT id, diagnosis,
       CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS binary
FROM Your_Table
```

Comment: I'm doing the coding in SAS, not sql.

Comment: @Uttara SAS supports proc SQL.